# Custom UI for KIE Workbench

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor, drools-kie-server

We are using KIE workbench for our business rule engine and is using guided UI for creating rules from UI.

**Problem:**
Business doesn't wants to use the UI provided by KIE workbench i.e. guided UI instead they wants to use custom UI where creation of business rules would be easy and more business user friendly.

I'm exploring the possibility of integrating a custom UI in another UI technology (angular js etc) with JBPM process?

> Is there any way to create custom UI for KIE Workbench?

Comment: As a dirty workaround I can suggest to use [spreadsheet decision tables](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.20.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#decision-tables-con_decision-tables). A custom web application can expose decent UI to fill the table and then generate `.xlsx` spreadsheet with the rule table and upload it to Drools.